# Why doesn't jQuery $(this).text() work inside a link?

Tags: jquery

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

```
<a href="javascript:alert($(this).text())">Alert This Text Here</a>
```

I am expecting it to alert "Alert This Text Here", but instead I get a jQuery error (G is undefined)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would assume that "this" has no association to the link you're clicking. It was never given association. `this` doesn't derive its association from markup/syntax.

The following works:

```
<a href="#" onClick="alert($(this).text());">Some Text</a>
```

Ideally, you want to keep your scripting separate from your markup. You should do it like this:

```
$("a.someClass").click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

This example would require your anchor to have a class="someClass" to function.

Comment: return false does the same thing as event.preventDefault()

Comment: You're right about the href javascript protocol has no context.  Try this.

     <a href="javascript:alert(this === window);">Try this.</a>

Returns true in FF, Safari and IE.  Probably Chrome too.  This probably follows spec, but I didn't find anything useful with a cursory search.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a id="alert">Alert This Text Here</a>
...
$(function() {
  $("#alert").click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
  });
});
```

As the above poster mentioned, the this needs to be in a selector to have context.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the "onclick" event handler, `this` will be available to obtain the `text()`.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery $(this) refers to a jQuery object usually in the context of a loop or some other selector.  So basically you want to select an object in jquery then use the $(this).

Example:

```
$("a").click(function(){alert($(this).text());});
```

This will work because the $(this) is in the context of the selected links.

I think you're getting it confused with the standard javascript "this" reference which will give you the current DOM object.

This post gives a nice explanation:
http://remysharp.com/2007/04/12/jquerys-this-demystified/